# Why Zorn's Lemma "fails" on nested boxes problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

## Backgound

My problem comes from the nested boxes problem. Consider a list of boxes. Each box has a length, width, and height. Since the boxes can be rotated those terms are interchangeable. The boxes have rectangular surfaces and can be nested inside each other. A box can nest inside another box if all its dimensions are less than the corresponding dimensions of the other. You may only nest a box such that the corresponding surfaces are parallel to each other. A box may not be nested along the diagonal. You cannot also put two or more boxes side by side inside another box.

Therefore, a box can be represented by a sorted (it's not hard to show that sorting the dimensions in ascending order won't affect the result of whether a box can be nested inside another) tuple of dimensions.  The set of boxes and the relation of being able to nested in another actually form a partially ordered set. And here comes my problem:

## Formalization

Let's use an example. Let $S=\{(1,1,1),\,(3,4,4),\,(2,5,5)\}$. We define relation $\le$ to be
$$
(x_1,y_1,z_1)\le(x_2,y_2,z_2) \text{ if and only if } x_1\le x_2,\,y_1\le y_2,\,\text{and }z_1\le z_2
$$
We see that $(S,\le)$ is a partially ordered set.

Now, all the totally ordered subset of $S$ are:
$$
S_1=\{(1,1,1),\,(3,4,4)\}\quad S_2=\{(1,1,1),(2,5,5)\}
$$
where $(3,4,4)$ is the upper bound of $S_1$, $(2,5,5)$ is the upper bound of $S_2$.

However, [Zorn's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) says:

> Suppose a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain (i.e. totally ordered subset) has an upper bound in $P$. Then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

Therefore, $S$ must have a maximal element. But it's obvious that $S$ doesn't have one.

Did I miss something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $\langle 3,4,4\rangle$ and $\langle 2,5,5\rangle$ are **maximal** elements of $S$: a maximal element is simply one that is not strictly less than any other element. Zorn’s lemma does not guarantee that $S$ has a **maximum** element, which I suspect is what you have in mind.

(By the way, $S$ has three other non-empty chains: they just aren’t maximal chains. Specifically, the other non-empty chains are the three singleton subsets.)

Comment: Ah... I see now. Both answers are great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Roun: You’re most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are confused as to the definition of maximal element. A maximal element of a partially ordered set $(S,\leq)$ is an element $s\in S$ such that if $t\in S$ and $s\leq t$, then $s=t$. It should be clear that the maximal elements of $S$ in your example are $(3,4,4)$ and $(2,5,5)$.